# How recursively use a directory structure in the new Hadoop API?

Tags: hadoop, recursion, hdfs

My file structure is the following:

```
/indir/somedir1/somefile
/indir/somedir1/someotherfile...
/indir/somedir2/somefile
/indir/somedir2/someotherfile...
```

I now want to pass everything recursively into a MR job, and I am using the new API. So I did:

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("/indir"));
```

But the job fails with:

```
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /indir/somedir1
```

I am using Hadoop 2.4 and in [this post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-hdfs-user/201307.mbox/%3C06006DDA5A27D541991944AC4117E7A96E1D5E6C@szxeml560-mbx.china.huawei.com%3E) it is stated that Hadoop 2's new API does not support recursive files. But I am wondering how this can be, as I think it is the most ordinary thing in the world to throw a large nested directory structure at a Hadoop job...

So, is this intended, or is this a bug? In both ways, is there another workaround than using the old API?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer myself. In the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3193) linked in the mentioned forum post, there are two comments on how it is done right:

1. Set `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive` to `true` (comment states `mapred.input.dir.recursive` but that is deprecated)
2. Use `FileInputFormat.addInputPath` to specify the input directory

With these changes, it works.

Comment: Nice finding bro. Why don't you accept the answer and seal it !

Comment: Because StackOverflow only lets me accept the answer in two days.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to configure it is via `FileInputFormat` class.

```java
FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
```